# Scrollable menu in mobile css

Tags: css, wordpress

On mobile, my wordpress blog shows the menu as three lines. Clicking on it it shows all the menu entries but I cannot scroll on the touch screen.

Which css property should I set for this menu so that I could see all of the menu by scrolling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the overflow CSS property for your menu-items container.

For example:
If you have menu items like this:

```
ul.menu-items-container {
   list-style:none;
}

ul.menu-items-container > li {
   /*CSS for individual menu items*/
}
```

then add `overflow: auto` or `overflow: scroll` like this:

```
ul.menu-items-container {
   list-style:none;
   overflow: auto;    /*or overflow: scroll*/
}
```

You can also target overflow on a specific axis like this:

```
ul.menu-items-container {
   list-style:none;
   overflow-y: auto;    /*or overflow-y: scroll*/
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need [Overflow](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_overflow.asp) css property.